# Request API with next js 14

Tags: javascript, next.js

This code isn't working;
this code is written by next js,
the error on the console is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/products/porducts.json 404 (not found)
```

And:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

```
fetch("/products/products.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Please, I need solve this problem.

I tried edit this code by a lot of ways and I asked chatGpt but it can't give me a solution for this problem as I expected and my tries don't work.

```
fetch("/products/products.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

[image]

Comment: Showing us the fetch code is quite pointless. If the server responds to the request for `/products/products.json` with a 404, then you either got the URL wrong to begin with, or something is going wrong in your server-side logic.

Answer (score 1):

The `products.json` file is a static file. Place the `products.json` file in the `/public` folder. So the path becomes `/public/products/products.json`.

If you put the `products.json` file in the `/app/products/products.json` folder, the file will not be read. Next.js will only read files in the `app` folder such as `page.jsx`, `not-found.jsx`, or `route.js`. The error of `Unexpected token '<' is not a valid JSON` is caused because when fetching `/products/products.json` it will fetch the `not-found` page.

Comment: Try writing the complete URL `fetch("https://.../products/products.json")`.

Comment: how to solve Unexpected token '<' is not a valid JSON

Comment: can you writ code on your IDE then take of the screen shot of the code and file explorer on you IDE, and thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Moaz**. Starting from Nextjs 13 going onward, the **app router** was introduced. It uses a different routing strategy compared to the older router (the **pages router**).

Of course the developer have the option to use the **app router** or the **pages router** or **both** at the same time. Even though the app router is newer that does not mean the pages router was deprecated or is not good.

To start using the **app router**, in your project root, **or** in the **src/** directory, create a folder called **app/**.

And in case you want to use the pages router, you'll create a folder called **pages/** instead. also either in the project root, or in the **src/** directory.

Anyway - now based on the screenshot you provided, your nextjs application is based on the **app router**. This is because your code is placed inside the **app/** directory.

In the **app router**, only certain files are served to the browser. Unlike the **pages router** where anything you place inside of it becomes a page accessible through the browser URL address bar.

now, you're placing your JSON file inside the app directory, and - you're trying to fetch it from a **client component** (*right?*). That will not work, this is because the rule I mentioned earlier. **Files inside the app directory are not served, only certain files**. (only the files called: *page.tsx*).

Now, in order to fetch this JSON file - move this file from the app directory to the **public/** directory.

Now, this file will be accessible through

```
http://localhost:3000/porducts.json
```

thus, change your code from:

```
fetch("/products/products.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

to:

```
fetch("/products.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```